# Plotting amplitude spectra of modulated message signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm trying to plot the amplitude spectrum of the modulated message signal,

[image]

I have managed to plot it by working through the maths, expanding out each trig function, and then drawing onto a graph with the below code

```
Plot[f, {f, 0, 1200}, PlotStyle -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 4},(*just gives the axes*)

 Epilog -> { (*amplitude lines*)

   Line[{{1000, 0}, {1000, 3}}], (*carrier*)
   Line[{{1010, 0}, {1010, 1.5}}], Line[{{990, 0}, {990, 1.5}}],
   Line[{{1030, 0}, {1030, 1}}], Line[{{970, 0}, {970, 1}}],
   Line[{{1050, 0}, {1050, 0.5}}], Line[{{950, 0}, {950, 0.5}}]
 }]
```

Which gives the desired plot,

[image]

I was wondering however, if there is an easier way to plot the amplitude spectrum from the equation?

To make it clearer, the x-axis is the half the frequency inside the trig function (eg. 2000\pi.t is 1000 on the x-axis) and the y is the coefficient of the trig function (ie. 3cos is 3 on the y-axis).

Comment: Your amplitude modulator is $3 \cos [20 \pi t + \pi/4]]...$.  Why not simply plot that?

Comment: `Fourier` . . ?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork he seems to want spectrum, i.e. frequency in x- axis

Comment: just plotting the 3Cos... gives the waveform of the modulated message, https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwr60w5geliyfqn/test.png?dl=0 

I want the amplitude spectra of this modulated waveform (as @BlacKow commented)

Comment: the message signal, 3cos(20pi t + pi/4) + 2sin(60pi t) - cos(100pi t). Sorry i just subbed that into the equation at the top without telling you!

Comment: using fourier function gave the output, https://www.dropbox.com/s/970q17r56h9vtld/output.png?dl=0 but dependant on how many data points i take i get two very different responses (also the x and y axis aren't as expected)

first plot is {t,0,0.3,0.001} and second is {t,0,1,0.001}

Comment: @FlamingSquirrel You want discrete spectrum, so Fourier won't work for you. See my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38163/discussion-between-flamingsquirrel-and-blackow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was too lazy to figure out your normalization, so I wrote down formulae for Fourier series.

```
f[t_] := 3 Cos[2000 Pi t] + 
   0.5 Cos[2000 Pi t] (3 Cos[20 Pi t + Pi/4] + 2 Sin [60 Pi t] - 
      Cos[100 Pi t]);
pl = {#, 1/(Pi) Abs@Integrate[f[t/Pi] E^-(I 2 # t), {t, -Pi, Pi}]} & /@
    Range[900, 1100, 10];
ListPlot[#, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> Full ] &@pl
```

[image]

Comment: That works! It seems my Mathematical expansion was a bit out!

Comment: Where did you get the Abs@Integrate.... Stuff from?

Comment: @FlamingSquirrel It's pretty much definition of Fourier coefficient. You can use `FourierCoefficient` but I encountered weird performance issue.

Comment: Okeydokey! Thank you for the solution. Will give FourierCoefficients a go myself - see what the performance issue is

Comment: @FlamingSquirrel [issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112191/fouriercoefficient-performance)

Comment: That is quite a difference!

Comment: So what was the code using FourierCoefficients ?

Comment: Instead of `Integrate[...]` it was `FourierCoefficient[f[t/(Pi)],t,#]`

Comment: Why is it t/Pi?

Comment: @FlamingSquirrel it's just scaling. FourierCoefficient deals with $\omega$, not freqquency... Ouch! I was unaccepted :(

Comment: Accepting this answer since the carrier signals amplitude in this is 3 (as expected) but 3.75 in the other solution… _not really sure why_

Answer (score 4):

```
f[om_] = FourierTransform[
  Cos[2000 Pi t] (3 + 1/2 (3 Cos[20 Pi t + Pi/4] + 2 Sin[60 Pi t] - 
     Cos[100 Pi t])), t, om]
```

[image]

The following transforms the above formula in graphics primitives `Line[...]` :

```
 ti00 = Collect[f[om], DiracDelta[_], coeff];
 ti01 = ti00 /. 
       coeff[c_] DiracDelta[s_] :> 
        With[{om3 = om /. Last[Solve[s == 0, {om}]]}, 
         Line[{{om3/(2 Pi), 0}, {om3/(2 Pi), Abs[c]}}]];

 Graphics[List @@ ti01, AspectRatio -> 0.2, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1200}, {0, 5}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

The negative frequencies are not shown.