# FourierCoefficient performance

Tags: performance-tuning, fourier-analysis

I encountered weird performance issue while using `FourierCoefficient[]`. I narrowed it down to calculating $n$-th coefficient for $\cos(nx)$.

```
fc[n_] := 
  AbsoluteTiming@
   Norm[FourierCoefficient[Cos[n t], t, n, 
     Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]];
fc1[n_] := 
  AbsoluteTiming@1/
    2 Norm[#[Cos[n t], t, n, 
       Assumptions -> 
        Element[n, Integers]] & /@ {FourierCosCoefficient, 
      FourierSinCoefficient}];
fc2[n_] := 
  AbsoluteTiming@1/(2 Pi) Abs@
    Integrate[Cos[n t] Exp[-I n t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
     Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]];

#[2000] & /@ {fc, fc1, fc2}
```

> ```
> {{31.760921, 1/2}, {0., 1/2}, {0., 1/2}}
> ```

Why is `fc[]` so slow? why would it be any different from `fc1[]`?

It also seems than the timing depends on $n$:

```
#[2] & /@ {fc, fc1, fc2}
```

> `{{0.023933, 1/2}, {0., 1/2}, {0., 1/2}}`

And it does depend on number representation:

```
#[2000.0] & /@ {fc, fc1, fc2}
```

> `{{0.211505, 0.5}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 0.5}}`

I have MMA 10.2, can anyone check this with the latest version please?