# How can I Plot DiracDelta function with complex number?

Tags: plotting

The function is:

```
y[w_]= 0.32 DiracDelta[(2.495*10^-21 + 0. I) + 1.054*10^-50 w] 
       + 1.19 DiracDelta[(1.979*10^-20 + 0. I) + 1.054*10^-58 w];
```

Question 1) How can I remove all component less than 10^(-22) in y[w_]?  (or remove "0.I")
Question 2) How I can Plot[y[w]]?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Look up `Chop[]`.

Comment: Concerning a way of representing `DiracDelta[]` with graphics primitives, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112193/5467) is a solution.

Comment: but I can't convert y[w_] to Fourier transform? which is the exactly function here I must use?

Answer (score 3):

(Extended comment)

Here is the solution exposed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112193/5467) adapted to your problem :

```
y[w_] = 0.32 DiracDelta[(2.495*10^-21) + 1.054*10^-50 w] + 
  1.19 DiracDelta[(1.979*10^-20) + 1.054*10^-58 w]

ti00 = Collect[y[w], DiracDelta[_], coeff]

ti01 = ti00 /. 
  coeff[c_] DiracDelta[exp_] :> 
   With[{ww = w /. Last[Solve[exp == 0, {w}]]}, 
    Line[{{ww/(2 Pi), 0}, {ww/(2 Pi), Abs[c]}}]]

Graphics[List @@ ti01 , AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still wonder why DiracDelta not reach infinity in your graphic?                                                                     Could you help me plot another function (it has a division)! z[w_]=0.32 DiracDelta[(2.495*10^-21 ) + 1.054*10^-50 w] + 
        1.19 DiracDelta[(1.979*10^-20) + 1.054*10^-58 w]/
  ( w (-8*10^-21 + 1.05*10^-34 w)^2 + 
 3.8*10^-25 (1.3
DiracDelta[(-2.23*10^-20) + 
      1.05*10^-34 w])

Comment: @Haimuoi If you see a Dirac as the limit of schrinking pulses with constant surfaces S, then S is the value that determine the strengh of the Dirac. The lines in the graphic are representing the S.
Concerning the second part of your comment, I have no answer.

Comment: Dear @andre.! Thank you for your help :) I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Round` to get rid of small component.

```
Round[1. + 10.^-5 I, 10.^-6]
```

> $1. + 0.00001 \rm I$

```
Round[1. + 10.^-5 I, 10.^-3]
```

> $1.$

For your code

```
y[w_,n_]= Round[0.32 DiracDelta[(2.495*10^-21 + 0. I) + 1.054*10^-50 w] 
           + 1.19 DiracDelta[(1.979*10^-20 + 0. I) + 1.054*10^-58 w],10.^-n];
```

to eliminate numbers less than `10^-n`

**How to Plot**

Here I define a plotting function `ddplot`

```
y[w_] = 0.32 DiracDelta[(2.495*10^-21 + 0. I) + 1.054*10^-50 w] + 
        1.19 DiracDelta[(1.979*10^-20 + 0. I) + 1.054*10^-58 w];
ddplot[n_] := ListPlot[Cases[y[0], x_ DiracDelta[y_] :> Round[{y, x}, 10.^-n]],
                       Filling -> Bottom]

ddplot[22]
ddplot[20]
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't work , Mathematica said "ListPlot::argx: ListPlot called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>" . Could you repair it?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? Are you using `y[w_]` or `y[w_,n_]`? For plotting you have to use y[w_],  similar to the one you wrote in your question.

Comment: Yes, I used y[w_] and version 9.0. But "0.I" is the result of previous calculations (in my progress).

Comment: hmm. What is the output of `y[0]`? Perhaps that is where I miss something !